# What I am not riddle ?Say my Name!

Tags: riddle

I have a number in me, but not Area-51

One of my Creator is a fruit, but he is not a plant

I have an unknown, but I am not unknown

I have Artificial Intelligence, but I am not a robot

Say my Name !!!

Comment: Thank you for bounties. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you are

> X Æ A-12 (Son of Elon Musk)

I have a number in me, but not Area-51

> 12

One of my Creator is a fruit, but he is not a plant

> The mother's name is Grimes, which is also the name of an apple (Grimes Golden)

I have an unknown, but I am not unknown

> X -> X was put in the name because it is the common unknown variable in mathematics

I have Artificial Intelligence, but I am not a robot

> Æ means AI in Elven language

Say my Name !!!

> X Æ A-12

Comment: if that's the correct creator, then "he" isn't right. Perhaps it's a reference to zhfxzryba?

Answer (score 2):

My version of the answer is: [AlphaZero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AlphaZero).

Number: 0.

Creator: DeepMind, the fruit of science and technology. Or, Demis Hassabis, paternal side coming from Greek nation, his name could be connected to the Greek deity Demeter, the goddess of agriculture, harvest and fertility.

Unknown: 0 ([nought, placeholder, nothing, empty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0#Etymology))

AI: [DeepMind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DeepMind) or AlphaZero itself.

I think your name is AlphaZero.